# mexFunction compiled in visual studio causes MATLAB to crash if there is any reference to any function

Tags: matlab, mex

Hello StackOverflow community

I have a very basic mexFunction implemented in Visual Studio 2013. I can compile a empty mexFunction as follows, and when I test it in MATLAB, it works perfectly:

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{

}
```

However, when I enter any function, the compilation is still successful but when I try to run in MATLAB, MATLAB crashes.

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    const char* message = "Hello World";
    mexPrintf(message);
}
```

This is as basic an example as humanly possible, and it causes MATLAB to crash. It does not use any of the inputs I provide.I have tried 0 inputs to 3 inputs:

```
cfg.i = 1;
cfg.o = 2;
cfg.p = 3;
mcx(cfg);
```

mcx is the name of the mex function compiled by visual studio. I clear my entire folder before re-compiling the mexFunction. Any help on this problem will be very helpful.

Compilation of this code is succesful but crashes MATLAB as well:

```
    #include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    mexPrintf("test");
}
```

Comment: you need to call it as `mcx()` right? that function has no inputs

Comment: just calling it as mcx() causes MATLAB to crash as well.

Comment: What about `mexPrintf("test");`

Comment: It also crashed MATLAB. When I attach visual studio to the MATLAB process, it says MATLAB.exe has triggered a breakpoint.